# How to Extend Content Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How can I extend the class Content Page to create a method that executes when it is the user's first time on a page?

(Xamarin.Forms)

Comment: You can make it on the view model or add a flag on the code behind to execute that method

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest way to do it:

```
public abstract class CustomContentPage : ContentPage
{
    private bool _appeared;

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (!_appeared)
        {
            OnFirstAppearing();

            _appeared = true;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void OnFirstAppearing();
}
```

Comment: That will not persist after app is killed and resumed. See my answer below, posted moments after yours. :-)

Comment: Good point, although it's not entirely clear from the question if the method should be called the first time the user visits the page *ever*, or within the session.

Answer (score 0):

First you will want to use [Application.Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.properties?view=xamarin-forms) dictionary so you can preserve the state of the application, i.e. whether the user has ever gone to the page.

So in the OnAppearing method override in your ContentPage subclass, check to see if you have set the property in the Application.Current.Properties dictionary to see if the page has been visited. If the key is not present, set it and do whatever you want for this first visit to the page. If the key is present, do whatever you want to do for subsequent visits to the page, e.g.:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (!Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("main_page_visited"))
        {
            Application.Current.Properties["main_page_visited"] = true;
            label.Text = "First Time visited";
        }
        else
        {
            label.Text = "Second+ Time visited";
        }

    }
}
```

The `Application.Current.Properties` gets saved automatically when the app exits.